# EasyOCR не видит видеокарту

Tags: python, cuda, gpu

EasyOCR не видит видеокарту RTX 2060 (for laptops) и выдаёт такую ошибку:

> CUDA not available - defaulting to CPU. Note: This module is much
> faster with a GPU.

Вот сам код:

```
import easyocr
read = easyocr.Reader(['uk', 'en'], gpu=True)
result = read.readtext('text.jpg', detail=0)
print(result)
```

CUDA_11.5.0_496.13 установлена, ноутбук: Acer Nitro 5.